# How can I find the X and Y intercepts on a circle, using the angle?

Tags: calculus, matrices, graphing-functions

[This is the exact situation I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecNl.png)

so while making a video game we ran into an issue with the bullet aim. The problem here is that we have only been given the angle and need to figure out how to calculate the (x ,y) intercepts.

we tried to using -sin(A) to find Y and -cos(A) to find X, but there was an exponential offset which we couldn't fix.

Ps* we are novice video game developers at best, any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are basically [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20polar%20coordinate,angle%20from%20a%20reference%20direction.).
So you can simply convert from polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ to cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$ using:

$$x=r \cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$y=r \cdot sin(\theta)$$

Where $\theta$ is your angle, and for your specific case $r=1$.
Also make sure you know what argumets your trig functions take (degrees or radians) because that can often cause trouble.

Not sure what you mean by exponential offset.

Comment: Your $\theta$ is not the OP's $A$, though.

Comment: You mean it's $-A$ because OP's angle is going clockwise?

Comment: The OP measures angles clockwise from "North"; you measure them counterclockwise from "East".